# mobile application difference between java and C#

Tags: c#, java, mobile

i need to build a mobile application to connect the mobile to a local server using Wi-Fi
which programming language i should use java or C#
and is there any problem in runnig a java application on a windows mobile ??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the mobile device that you're targeting.  RIM, iOS, Android, Symbian based phones all have different supported development environments/languages.  You could use Java, C#, J2ME, objective-C + goodness knows what else depending on your target device.

Comment: Um, so - what's your target device? :)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which mobile market you're focusing on: These are the language supported by various Operating Systems found on mobiles device(s):

- Symbian devices can also be programmed using Python, Java ME, Flash Lite, Ruby, .NET, Web Runtime (WRT) Widgets and Standard C/C++.
- BlackBerry OS supports [Java ME (Mobile Edition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Micro_Edition)
- iOS (for iPhone and iPod Touch) applications are written in [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C).
- Windows 7 Mobile can be written in Visual Studio with the Windows Phone SDK (downloadable from Microsoft).

To run it on all OS platforms, you will have to code many versions of the same project.